# how to detect incoming and outgoing calls, if app not in background

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, call

How to detect calls if app not in background. Used BroadcastReceiver, but it is not triggering if app killed.

```
public class CallStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Check if the intent action is related to phone state
    if (intent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        // Get the new call state from the intent
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        // Check the call state and start your service accordingly
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // Call is ringing
            // Start your service here
        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            // Call ended or no active call
            // Stop or restart your service here as per your requirement
        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // Call answered or outgoing call
            // Start your service here
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If your app is not running in the background, it is not possible to detect incoming or outgoing calls directly within your app. This is because Android platforms have strict privacy

Comment: How the Truecaller showing their screen, while ringing? @FayyazHussain

Comment: Did you register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: and also request the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: Given permission and registered in Manifest